# Proof of an open set or closed set

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I'm struggling on a proof that I can't proof correctly.
Let $A=\mathbb{Z}$, $B=\{n-\frac{1}{2n} | n \in \mathbb{N}*\}$
I could prove easily that A is a closed set and B as well :

$\overline A =$ $\mathbb{R}$\ $\{\mathbb{Z}\}\Leftrightarrow \overline A = ]\ n;n+1[$, $n\in \mathbb{N}*$ so $\overline A$ is an open set $\Rightarrow$ $A$ is closed.

$\overline B = ]-\infty;\frac{1}{2}[\ \bigcup\ (\ \bigcup_{1}^{\infty}]\ n - \frac{1}{2n}; n+1 - \frac{1}{2n+2}[)$ is another open set so $\Rightarrow$ $B$ is closed.

but then I have a problem when I have to **prove that $A+B$ is not a closed set**.

here's what I do :

$A+B=\{a+n-\frac{1}{2n}| \ a\in \mathbb{Z}, n\in \mathbb{N}*\}$ but then I guess that $\mathbb{N}*\subset \mathbb{Z}$ so I though I could rewrite : $A+B= \{p -\frac{1}{2n}|\ p \in \mathbb{Z}, n\in \mathbb{N} \}$

then, I wanted to prove that $\overline{A+B}$ is a closed set but here's what it is :

$\overline{A+B}=$ $\mathbb{R}$\ $\{p-\frac{1}{2n}| \ p\in \mathbb{Z}, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ but for me it is an open set because it seems just as $B$ but with $p\in\mathbb{Z}$

so here would be my **question** : why would $\mathbb{R}$\ $\{p-\frac{1}{2n}| \ p\in \mathbb{Z}, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ be an open set when I just proved that $\mathbb{R}$\ $\{n-\frac{1}{2n}| \ n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a closed one ?
it may be obvious but I really don't see it.

thank you for your help !

Comment: Side note: it is a really bad idea to denote the complement of the set $S$ by $\overline{S}$ when doing topology. $\overline{S}$ is pretty universally understood as the _closure_ of $S$.

Comment: Yea you're right I'm just used to it but I should change my notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$-\frac{1}{2n} \in A+B$ and you can show that $0 \not \in A+B$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
okay so let's try : $-\frac{1}{2n} \in A+B$ so it means that $0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ but $0\notin \mathbb{N}*$ so $0\notin A+B$
is it enough to conclude that $A+B$ is an open set because I found one point which is not inside my set ?

Comment: It proves that $A+B$ is not closed, since a closed set contains the limits of all of its sequences.

Comment: alright thank you very much